# If $p$ is a factor of $m^2$ then $p$ is a factor of $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm a complete beginner and not sure where to go with this proof of Euclid's lemma. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> If $m$ is a positive integer and a prime number $p$ is a factor of $m^2,$ then  $p$ is a factor of $m.$

So far I have:

Since we know that $m$ is a positive integer, then $m^2$ must also be positive.
We also know that $p$ is positive integer, since it is a prime number.

So $m^2 = p*k$ where $k$ is positive since both $m^2$ and $p$ are positive.
Therefore, $k$ is greater than or equal to $1.$

...?

Comment: Do you know about unique prime factorizations?

Comment: Reading up on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about prime factorization.. the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) states that every non-zero integer has a unique (up to ordering) factorization into products of prime powers. That is,
$$ m = \pm p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_n^{k_n} $$
where $p_i$'s are primes and $k_i > 0$ for all $i.$ ($\pm$ based on the sign of $m.$)

Now what is the prime factorization of $m^2$? It's
$$ m = p_1^{2k_1} p_2^{2k_2} \cdots p_n^{2k_n}. $$

Can you now use this information to show that $p \ | \ m^2 \implies p \ | \ m$?

Comment: Yes! working on it..thanks for your help.

Comment: I understand the logic, but I'm not sure how to word it correctly according to proof standards.

Comment: If $p | m^2$ then $p | \prod_i p_i^{k_i}.$ By Euclid's lemma, $p | p_i^{k_i}$ for some $i.$ But both $p, p_i$ are prime, and the only divisors of $p_i^{k_i}$ are $1, p_i, p_i^{k_j}$ for $1 < j < k_i.$ Hence $p = p_i$ for some $i.$ So now we can write $m$ as $m = p_i \prod_{j, j\neq i} p_j^{k_j} = pr,$ for some integer $r.$ I.e. $p | m.$

Comment: @rookie_02 see my comment above.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If $p$ is not a prime factor of $m$ then $gcd(p,m)=1$ since $p$ is prime. So there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
xp + ym = 1
$$
So
$$
xmp = m - ym^2.
$$
Since $p \mid m^2$, this implies $p \mid m$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Put $\,k = m\,$ in **Euclid's Lemma**: $ $ prime $\:p\:|\:m\,k\:\Rightarrow\: p\:|\:m\ \ or\ \ p\:|\:k,\,$  proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260621/242) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216213/if-a-prime-p-mid-ab-then-p-mid-a-or-p-mid-b-euclids-lemma) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252746/prove-euclids-lemma-in-a-ufd-gcda-b-1-a-mid-bc-rightarrow-a-mid-c).