# If a prime $p$ divides $n^2$ then it also divides $n$ - Is this proof correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-factorization, square-numbers

I'm learning Real Analysis by myself and I wanted to prove that if a prime $p$ divides $n^2$ where $n$ is an integer, then $p$ divides $n$ itself. I saw that proving this is the same as saying that the prime factors of $n^2$ are "the same" than those of $n$.

In this case, assume there exists a prime factor $a_q$ in $n^2$ which is not in $n$ (proof by contradiction). By Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, we can represent $n^2$ as $n^2= a_1 * a_2 * ... * a_x * a_q$, where every $a$ is prime and $n=k_1 * k_2 * ... * k_y$ (every $k$ is also prime). We know that $\frac{n^2}{n}=n$. So (by susbstituting):

$\frac{n^2}{n}= \frac{a_1*...*a_x*a_q}{k_1*...*k_y}=n \rightarrow \frac{a_1*...*a_x}{k_1*...*k_y}=\frac{n}{a_q}$

Because $\frac{n}{a_q}$ it's not an integer (initial statement), there's at least one $a_s$ in the left side of the equation that is not divisible by any $k$. Now we have two factors of $n^2$ that don't divide $n$. We can repeat this process,

$\frac{a_1*...*a_x*a_s}{k_1*...*k_y}=\frac{n}{a_q} \rightarrow \frac{a_1*...*a_x}{k_1*...*k_y}=\frac{n}{a_q*a_s}$,

for each prime factor of $n^2$ which means that there's no factor $a_i$ in $n^2$ divisible by any factor $k_j$ of $n$. But we knew that $\frac{n^2}{n}=n$, hence we have a contradiction ($n^2$ is not divisible by $n$). So there's no prime factor $p$ in $n^2$ that does not divide $n$ itself $\rightarrow$ every prime factor $p$ in $n^2$ also divides $n$.

I'm obviously not an expert in demonstrations so I want to know if this is a valid argument. I'm also aware of Euclid's Lemma, but for this case, ignore it.

Comment: As in the answer from Alex R., an important part of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is that  for $1<n\in \Bbb Z^+,$ the finite sequence $p_1,...,p_m$ such that $n=\prod_{j=1}^mp_j$ is $unique,$ up to a re-arrangement of the order of the terms $p_1,...,p_m$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $p$ is a factor of $m^2$ then $p$ is a factor of $m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176053/if-p-is-a-factor-of-m2-then-p-is-a-factor-of-m)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shorter way would be to write $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ (where each $\alpha_i>0$) by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Then $n^2= p_1^{2\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{2\alpha_k}$. The only primes that divide $n^2$ are $p_1,\cdots,p_k$ and these clearly also divide $n$.

Comment: Woah, thanks! I'm just a beginner, so this helps me a lot.

Comment: @DataSpace Unfortunately this answer is wrong - your proof is not correct. The claim in the first sentence of the 3rd paragraph is not true, e.g. $p/p^2$ is not an integer, but but there is no prime in the numerator that is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: @BillDubuque If $\frac{p}{p^2} = \frac{n}{a_q}$ then $a_q = n*p$ (simple algebra), this contradicts the idea that every $a$ is prime. So your counterexample is not valid.Sorry for the delay :s

Comment: @BillDubuque Nevertheless, it is true that this proof is not clear at all and contains argumentative"holes". It is, of course, a better idea to just take Alex's proof.

Comment: @DataSpace But I didn't claim it equals $n/a_q$. The point is that your argument doesn't handle such multiple factors that may occur in the (reducible) fraction.

Comment: @DataSpace To be rigorous one needs to be very *precise* when making such arguments.  FTA (or equivalent) is typically used in *multiple* places in such arguments and it is essential to *explicitly* mention *all* such uses (else the argument may be circular). For example, the above answer is a *sketch* of one common proof, but it needs to be expanded to be completely rigorous.

Comment: @BillDubuque Of course, rigor is the fundamental property of math. As a beginner, I hope to achieve, one day, this mathematical maturity. Thanks for the advice, I'll look how to improve this.

Comment: @DataSpace It is esp. subtle here because we have such strong prior *intuition* about the integers. But such knowledge is usually gained *empirically* rather than *deductively* so one has to be very careful not to confuse the two.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach. Unique prime factorization of $n,$ for $1<n\in \Bbb N,$ follows from the Lemma that if $a,b,c\in \Bbb Z$ and $\frac {ab}{c}\in \Bbb Z$ while $\gcd (a,c)=1$ then $\frac {b}{c}\in \Bbb Z.$ The Lemma follows from something called Bezout's Identity, although it is implicit in Euclid's algorithm for computing a $\gcd$ : For any  $a,b\in \Bbb Z$ (not both $0$) there exist $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ such that $ax+by=\gcd (a,b).$

Let $p$ be prime and let  $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $p|n^2.$ Let $m=\gcd (p,n).$ Since $m$ divides the prime $p$ and $m\ge 1,$ we have $m=1$ or $m=p.$

Now there exist $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ such that $px+ny=m,$ so $\frac {(m-px)^2}{p}=\frac {n^2y^2}{p}=\frac {n^2}{p}\cdot y^2\in \Bbb Z.$ But if $m=1$ then $\frac {(m-px)^2}{p}=\frac {1-2px+p^2x^2}{p}=\frac {1}{p}-2x+px^2\in \Bbb Z,$ implying $\frac {1}{p}\in \Bbb  Z,$ which is absurd.

So, since we can't have $m=1,$ we have $m=p$. And since $m=\gcd (p,n)|n,$ we have  therefore $p|n.$

Comment: As  matter of style, we could also say that $p|n^2\implies$ $ p|n^2y^2=$ $(m-px)^2=$ $=m^2+p(-2mx+px^2)\implies$ $ p|m^2,$ to show that $m\ne 1$.

Comment: <3 I really liked this proof, thanks for such logical piece.

Comment: @DataSpace If you're going to permit Bezout then it's easy:

$$\,p\mid nn,\ p\nmid n\,\Rightarrow\, kn\!+\!jp = 1\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid knn\!+\!jpn =  (kn\!+\!jp)n = n\qquad\qquad$$

Or, equivalently said in terms of gcds $\ \ p\mid nn,pn\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid (nn,pn)=(n,p)n = n.\ $ This is essentially a special-case of the Bezout-based proof of EL = Euclid's Lemma ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) for various proofs of EL)